# Time series analysis: how to rank the ability of predictors to predict physically-based model outputs

Tags: time-series

I have a complex physically-based biological model which solves partial differential equations to predict the number of individuals in a certain community as a function of temperature, salinity, and chlorophyll concentration. Therefore I have 20 years of daily data for the number of individuals N (i.e., the model output) and measured temperature, salinity, and chlorophyll concentration (i.e., the model inputs). We would like to rank the predictors based on how much they affect the model output. Note that we cannot add and remove predictors from the physically-based model. It will be both unphysical and too computationally expensive.
See below a quick drawing of the model output (N, first plot), and one of the predictors (temperature, T, second plot) for reference. They vary seasonally and there is a clear lag between the two time series.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a few commonly used ways to "rank" predictors based on "how much".
You can standardize your predicters (z score). The absolute magnitude of each predictor's coefficient will be a standardized effect on the response.

You can, if your model permits it, calculate partial R2 (omega square, eta square) for each coefficient. This will estimate the amount of variation that each predictor accounts for in the nodel.

These two methods roughly tend to agree with each other, but not always. Standardized coefficients can be had for any model. Partial R2 can be trickier to get for some models.

Comment: Thank you. Which coefficient are you referring to? Are you suggesting to use a regression? If yes, which type of regression? Linear, not linear, autoregressive, arima?

Comment: Just to be clearer, I edited the question by specifying that we do not have model coefficients, because I am not using a statistical model, but a physically-based biological model which solves partial differential equations to predict the number of individuals in a certain community as a function of temperature, salinity, and chlorophyll concentration.